# How can I make different sections of a border-bottom different colors?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am creating a web page just to work on my jquery, (I won't host it or anything) and I was creating a navbar, and had a question. I want the navigation bar border-bottomss to be brown, red, orange, yellow, then white, instead of just red for all five. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        });
        </script>
        <title>Fountain of Darkness</title>
        <style>
        body {
            background: #272733;
            font-family:'century gothic';
        } #main {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        } #navbar ul {
            list-style-type:none;
            overflow:hidden;
        } #navbar li {
            float:left;
        } #navbar a {
            display:block;
            width:80px;
            height:40px;
            border-bottom:3px solid red;
            text-decoration:none;
            margin-right:10px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">

        <div id="logo">
            Fountain of Darkness
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.hmtl">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.hmtl">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.hmtl">ARCHIVE</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.hmtl">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.hmtl">NEWS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to do this with the code I have? thanks!

EDIT: I wasn't asking for a jquery answer! That was just some extra info about why.

Comment: you want five different solid colors of the five links, or a border bottm which animates through 5 colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give each link a different class and style them appropriately.

```
<li><a class = "brown" href="index.hmtl">HOME</a></li>
<li><a class = "red" href="index.hmtl">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a class = "orange" href="index.hmtl">ARCHIVE</a></li>
<li><a class = "yellow" href="index.hmtl">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a class = "white" href="index.hmtl">NEWS</a></li>

#navbar a.brown {
    border-color:brown;
}

#navbar a.red {
    border-color:red;
}

#navbar a.orange {
    border-color:orange;
}

#navbar a.yellow {
    border-color:yellow;
}

#navbar a.white {
    border-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid this, but it seems to be the easiest way!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css3 :nth-child() selector.

```
#navbar li:nth-child(1) a {
    border-bottom:3px solid red;
}
#navbar li:nth-child(2) a {
    border-bottom:3px solid blue;
}
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hDhQB/

Can you use it yet? http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: It's really powerful - here's a good article on it: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 1):

As it's just for learning, and you're asking for a jQuery solution, something like this would work :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = ['brown', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'];
    $('#navbar a').css('border-bottom-color', function(i) {
        return colors[i];
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BU58q/1/)

It would be better to just use CSS for this on a production site.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't looking for jquery! Sorry if I wasn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to do this would be wrong. You're asking about styling elements statically, not dinamically. That's something you can do with normal CSS classes.

```
.white {
   border-color: white;
}
.blue {
   border-color: blue;
}
// ecc...
```

Then

```
<li class="white"><a href="index.hmtl">HOME</a></li>
<li class="blue"><a href="index.hmtl">ABOUT</a></li>
// ecc...
```

you now have CSS classes `white` and `blue` which you can reuse everywhere on your project. Alternatively, you could name them `home_color` and `about_color`. But that depends on the architecture of your page. None of the approaches require a single line of JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing. (I wasn't asking for a jquery answer though, that was just fluff for the question.